# Are there any specific Mantras mentioned in scriptures that reduce sexual lust?

Tags: life, sex, spirituality, desire, spiritual

My question is more pertaining towards sexual lust/desires/infatuations.

I want to know if our scriptures have mentioned specific Mantras or something related that can be done by a devotee to reduce them.

I am strictly looking for Mantras, etc and not generic statements about cultivating knowledge about the same, etc. as mentioned in several scriptures for example,

Gita verse 3.37
“ The Blessed Lord said: It is lust only, Arjuna, which is born of contact with the material modes of passion and later transformed into wrath, and which is the all-devouring, sinful enemy of this world.”

Gita verse 3.41
“ Therefore, O best of the Bharatas, in the very beginning bring the senses under control and slay this enemy called desire, which is the embodiment of sin and destroys knowledge and realization”

Comment: There is a mudra called the Kamajayi mudra. Although not a mantra but still worth trying to see if it works or not. It is also said the Guru given mantra (Guru mantra) reduces lust if chanted repeatedly on a daily basis.

Comment: If you are walking from Mumbai to Delhi, the closer you get to Delhi the farther away from Mumbai. You need not worry about how far from Mumbai you are. Walk to the Lord, the closer you get, the farther away will be lust. It will become more and more distant by itself. A yogi once carried hot chilis with him and trained his mind to stop thinking lustful thoughts by chewing hot chilis whenever his mind wandered to lustful thoughts. The chilis were so hot that the hot taste drove out all thoughts except the heat on his tongue.

Comment: Om kāma dahanāahya namaha is the Hanuman mantra to control lust (don't think it is in scriptures but is quite popular) .

Comment: Raam naam is a mahamantra, which not only removes lust but gives liberation

Comment: Ahara Niyam (food control) is the first foundation, Indriya Nigraha (sense control) is second, Mantra (mind control) is last step. Without first two, doing last step is probably pointless at best, and dangerous at worst. Avoid meat, alcohol, eggs, onion, garlic. Avoid sensual movies, stories, fantasizing (porn/masturbation etc.). Once you are confident that you won't slide back into those first two steps, start with Mantras to go to higher steps.

Comment: As far as I know there is not a specific mantra for this. There are mantra's to control senses but nothing for reducing sexual desires.

Answer (score 4):

Sexual Lust is one of the forms of Kāma (or desires). And Kāma is very difficult to control.

However, as per an excerpt from the  Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa, we may deduce that recital of the monosyllabled bījākṣara mantra - "klim or klīṃ  ( क्लीं ), may help control and overcome sexual lust.

---

There's an excerpt in the  Devī Bhāgavata Purāṇa, where Indra, out of the fear of losing his Heaven, conspires to disturb the penance of the Nara and Nārāyaṇa Ṛṣis, and employs the god of desires - Kāmamadeva for the task, after several unsuccessful attempts previously.

> [Chapter
> 5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57169.html),
> Book 4,  Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa
>
> व्यास उवाच इति तस्य वचः श्रुत्वा शक्रं प्राह मनोभवः । वासवाद्य
> करिष्यामि कार्यं ते मनसेप्सितम् ॥ ४६ ॥
>
> > 46. Vyāsa said :-- Kāmadeva, on hearing the king of the Devas, addressed him thus :-- O Indra! Today I will fulfill all your desires.
>
> ---
>
> यदि विष्णुं महेशं वा ब्रह्माणं वा दिवाकरम् । ध्यायन्तौ तौ तदास्माकं
> भवितारौ वशौ मुनी ॥ ४७ ॥
>
> > 47. **But there is one word. If these two ascetics be meditating Viṣṇu, Śiva or Brahmā or the Sun, then I will be able to bring them under my
> >     control.**
>
> ---
>
> देवीभक्तं वशीकर्तुं नाहं शक्तः कथञ्चन । कामराज महाबीजं चिन्तयन्तं
> मनस्यलम् ॥ ४८ ॥
>
> > 48. **And if they be meditating on the Great Seed Mantra, the root of all Māyā, and the great Kāmavījam (klim/klīṃ - क्लीं), the king of the Kāma, I will never
> >     be able to subdue such a devotee of the Highest Devī.**
>
> ---
>
> तां देवीं चेन्महाशक्तिं संश्रितौ भक्तिभावतः । न तदा मम बाणानां गोचरौ
> तापसौ किल ॥ ४९ ॥
>
> > 49. If these two ascetics have devotedly taken refuge of the Great Power Mahā Devī, then they will not come under the sight of my arrows.
>
> English translation by Swami Vijñanananda

From this excerpt, we may conclude that the practitioner of the Kāmavījam which is "klim or klīṃ  ( क्लीं ), the bīja-mantra of the Great Mahā Devī, can control lustful desires and thoughts.

Of course, one must be initiated into these mantras, by a qualified preceptor, for them to be effective.

**But nonetheless, as per the above excerpt from the Devī Bhāgavatapurāṇa, the monosyllabled bījākṣara mantra - `"klim or klīṃ  ( क्लीं )` may be said to be effective in reducing sexual lust or any forms of  Kāma (or desires) in general.**