# How to eliminate Kaama?

Tags: kama, desire, purushartha

Kaama is very problematic . It makes us do adharma.

How to eliminate it ? What are the ways through which we can overcome Kaama.

Comment: Generic Term Kaama referes to just desire but based  on your question context of adharma i persume that its sexsual desire.. Kanchi mahaperiyama doesnt eat food for 7 days.. without water.. only theertha.. would have controlled absoluetly. Aqgara niyamana.. Ekadhasi upavasa.. Japa. achamana.. will do.. not eating food from strangers or hotel. No onion garlic food..

Answer (score 1):

Kama doesn't need to be eliminated completely. It needs to be controlled, as per the Dharma, to be followed by a householder is a must for societal order, and slowly, and slowly through penance (tapas) in the form of vows, sacrifices, charity, fasts, etc. it need to be overcome.

Even, so then Kama is difficult to vanquish or eliminate completely, for an average person, for kama (desires) is the root cause of material existence.

---

### View 1:

In this regard, the following excerpt from the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa maybe helpful.

> [Chapter 238](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502217.html), Tīrtha-māhātmya, Nāgara-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa
>
> 17. It should be understood that Śauca (purity is of two types: external and internal. Cleaning with water is th.e external one and
>     purification through faith is the internal one.
> 18. Curbing of the sense-organs should be practised. It is the greatest feature of Tapas. Cessation of fickleness of the senses
>     during Cāturmāsya will he the greatest Tapas.
> 19. By controlling the horses in the form of sense-organs, one can augment one’s happiness. The same horses (sense-organs) going astray
>     cause one to fall into Naraka along with the vital airs.
> 20. One should curb the atrocious she-alligator in the form of Mamatā (feeling of ownership) after rebuking it. Tapas alone increases the
>     weightiness of men always particularly in Cāturmāsya.
> 21. **This Kāma (lust) is a great enemy. One should vanquish it alone steadfastly. Those who have conquered Kama are noble-souled ones. The
>     entire universe is conquered by them.**
> 22. **The conquest of Kāma, the victory over wishful volition is always the root of Tapas. It is the very root of Tapas,**
> 23. **That alone is the greatest wisdom, by which Kāma is vanquished. The same in Cāturmāsya they call as the greatest Tapas. It yields
>     excellent benefit.**

- Thus vows like those of Cāturmāsya, and other important fasts like Ekadashi, Sivaratri, Navarātris, et al, done as per dharmika injunctions are conducive in regulating the enemy of Kama.

---

### View 2:

In this regard we get a beautiful passage from Mahabharata itself, which is known as **Kama-Gita** found in the Section 13 of the Ashwamedha parva.

Sri Krishna himself recites this to Yuddhishthira, declaring the unconquerable nature of kama (desires)

> #### [Kâma-Gitã](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14013.htm), Mahabharata
>
> Sri Krishna Said -
>
> By way of illustration of this truth, the sages versed in ancient
> lore, recite these Gathas called by the name of Kamagita, do thou O
> Yudhishthira, listen to the recital of them in detail. (Kama says) No
> creature is able to destroy me without resorting to the proper methods
> (viz., subjugating of all desires and practice of Yoga etc.) **If a man
> knowing my power, strive to destroy me by muttering prayers etc., I
> prevail over him by deluding him with the belief that I am the
> subjective ego within him. If he wish to destroy me by means of
> sacrifices with many presents, I deceive him by appearing in his mind
> as a most virtuous creature amongst the mobile creation, and if he
> wish to annihilate me by mastering the Vedas and Vedangas, I over
> reach him by seeming to his mind to be the soul of virtue amongst the
> immobile creation.** And if the man whose strength lies in truth, desire
> to overcome me by patience, I appear to him as his mind, and thus he
> does not perceive my existence, and if the man of austere religious
> practices, desire to destroy me by means of asceticism, I appear in
> the guise of asceticism in his mind, and thus he is prevented from
> knowing me, and the man of learning, who with the object of attaining
> salvation desires to destroy me, I frolic and laugh in the face of
> such a man intent on salvation. **I am the everlasting one without a
> compeer, whom no creature can kill or destroy. For this reason thou
> too, O prince, divert thy desires (Kama) to Virtue, so that, by this
> means, thou mayst attain what is well for thee.** Do thou therefore make
> preparations for the due performance of the horse sacrifice with
> presents, and various other sacrifices of great splendour, and
> accompanied with presents. Let not therefore grief overpower thee
> again, on beholding thy friends lying slain on the battlefield. Thou
> canst not see the men slain in this battle alive again. Therefore
> shouldst thou perform magnificent sacrifices with presents, so that
> thou mayst attain fame in this world, and reach the perfect way
> (hereafter)."
>
> English Translation by K.M. Ganguli

The above idea is beautifully summarized by Swami Sivananda in his lecture on Purity.

So basically, in the words of [Swami Sivananda](https://www.dlshq.org/messages/purity/)

> The desire says, *“People try to conquer me, but they do not know that
> even the desire to conquer me is a desire, they don’t understand that,
> so I am behind all their attempts.”*
>
> **Desire for God sublimates all other mortal desires. The higher absorbs
> the lower, the lower should be transmuted to the higher by meditation.**

---

So the answer is, to conquer kama, one must leave all the fruits of their karma to the God ([BG 18.66](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18/verse/66)), become [Stithaprajña](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46723/17833), and [perform karma, in conjunction with penance (like sacrifice, fasts, etc.) as per their Dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51191/17833).

Comment: Also another [relevant answer is here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51439/17833)

Comment: Excellently composed and a very well written Answer Sir!
Upvoted!!!